# Twilio: How to buy number through nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-node

I need to buy twilio numbers through nodejs. I could not find any answer regarding that. Is it really possible to buy twilio number through node.js ?

I really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Alan's response for Twilio's docs. In short:

1. create a folder "*twilio-node-numbers*", open a terminal and change to this folder
2. run "**npm init -y**"
3. run "**npm install twilio**"
4. create a "*.env*" file, add your Twilio credentials you can find on your Twilio console

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=AC...
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=4f...
```

5. create a "*get_available_numbers.js*" file

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.availablePhoneNumbers('CA')
    .local
    .list({ areaCode: 604, limit: 20 })
    .then(local => local.forEach(l => console.log(l.friendlyName)));
```

> CA is the country code and 604 is the area code

6. run "**node get_available_numbers.js**"

> You will get a list of available phone numbers based on the country code and area code you provided in the get_available_numbers.js

7. create a "*buy_phone_number.js*" file

```js
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.incomingPhoneNumbers
    .create({ phoneNumber: '+16047574779' })
    .then(incoming_phone_number => console.log(incoming_phone_number.sid));
```

> Where +16047574779 is one of the phone numbers from the list you got after running "node get_available_number.js"

8. run "**node buy_phone_number.js**"

> You will get a response with information about your provisioned phone number

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the relevant documentation.

[IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource)

Reference the Node.js code sample: "Provision a Phone Number"

You can get a list of available numbers using another API:

[AvailablePhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumber-resource)

and the associated sub-resources on that page (Local, Toll Free, Mobile).